# How to get the correct XPath?

Tags: xpath, firebug, google-chrome-devtools, scrape

I am new to the XML Path Language. What I want is to use a tool to get the XPath to use in a script for scraping content.

**For example:**

On http://econpy.pythonanywhere.com/ex/001.html I want to get all buyer's names.

I have tried Firebug and the Chrome DevTools but they both seem to produce a path, which does not work for my purposes.

That is, I get `/html/body/div[2]/div` whereas it should be `//div[@title="buyer-name"]/text()`.

(I used http://docs.python-guide.org/en/latest/scenarios/scrape/).

Any suggestions will be much appreciated.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There's a Firebug extension called [FirePath](https://addons.mozilla.org/firefox/addon/firepath/), which enhances Firebug's features related to XPaths. Also there was a new feature implemented into Firebug lately, which allows to [copy the minimal XPath](https://code.google.com/p/fbug/issues/detail?id=7120).

Both of them create paths based on elements with IDs, though, so I created an [enhancement request for Firebug](https://code.google.com/p/fbug/issues/detail?id=7191) to allow what you're asking for. And I also commented on an existing [feature request for FirePath](http://code.google.com/p/firepath/issues/detail?id=12), which targets this.

Comment: Great you've implemented the relative xpath enhancement Sebastian! I can see it's still an open issue, is there still a way to install it in Firefox? Thanks

Comment: Actually it was Jakob who implemented the feature in Firebug (for elements with ID). The open issue relates to relative XPaths based on elements *without* ID. As the issue is still open, it's not available in Firebug yet. If you want to have that feature available, you may want to write a patch for [Firebug.next](https://github.com/firebug/firebug.next).